# Follow up question to: Prove that $\dfrac{g(x,u_{n})}{\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert ^{p-1}}\rightarrow g_{0}$ weakly in $L^{\overline{p}}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

This is a follow up question of the question [Prove that $\dfrac{g(x,u_{n})}{\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert ^{p-1}}\rightarrow g_{0}$ weakly in $L^{\overline{p}}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202404/prove-that-dfracgx-u-n-left-vert-u-n-right-vert-p-1-rightarrow-g)

Let $\Omega
 \subset
  \mathbb{R}^{N}$
  be a smooth bounded domain , $g:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
  is a Caratheodory function such that $g(x,t)=0$
  for $t\leq0$
 . Suppose that there exist function $a\in L^{r}$
  and $d\in L^{p'}$
  such that

$\left|g(x,t)\right|\leq a(x)t^{p-1}+d(x)$

with $r>N/p$
  if $1<p\leq N$
  and $r=1$
  if $p>N$
 ; $p'$
  is Holder conjugate of $p$

Let $\left\{ u_{n}\right\} \subset W_{0}^{1,p}$
  be a sequence such that $\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert \rightarrow\infty$
  as $n\rightarrow\infty$
 . Let us define $v_{n}=u_{n}/\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert $
 . Hence $\left\Vert v_{n}\right\Vert =1$
  and we may assume that $v_{n}\rightarrow v$
  weakly in $W_{0}^{1,p}$
 . Prove that $\dfrac{g(x,u_{n})}{\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert ^{p-1}}\rightarrow g_{0}$
  weakly in $L^{\overline{p}}$
  for some $\overline{p}>p*'$
  if $p<N$
  and $\overline{p}=1$
  if $p\geq N$
 .

The case $p>N$
 :

$\left\Vert g(x,u)\right\Vert _{L^{1}}\leq\left\Vert a\right\Vert _{L^{1}}\left\Vert u^{p-1}\right\Vert _{L^{\infty}}+\left\Vert d\right\Vert _{L^{1}}$

The case $p=N$
 :

$\left\Vert g(x,u)\right\Vert _{L^{1}}\leq\left\Vert a\right\Vert _{L^{r}}\left\Vert u^{p-1}\right\Vert _{L^{r'}}+\left\Vert d\right\Vert _{L^{1}}=\left\Vert a\right\Vert _{L^{r}}\left\Vert u\right\Vert _{L^{r'(p-1)}}^{p-1}+\left\Vert d\right\Vert _{L^{1}}\leq C\left\Vert a\right\Vert _{L^{r}}\left\Vert u\right\Vert _{W_{0}^{1,p}}^{p-1}+\left\Vert d\right\Vert _{L^{1}}$

How should I do with the case $p>N$
  to obtain an estimate similar with the case $p=N$
 ? What should I do next after that because $\dfrac{g(x,u_{n})}{\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert ^{p-1}}$
  is bounded in $L^{1}\left(\Omega\right)
  \nRightarrow$
 we can find a subsequence $\{u_{n_{k}}\}$
  of $\{u_{n}\}$
  such that ${\displaystyle \frac{g(x,u_{n_{k}})}{\|u_{n_{k}}\|_{W^{1,p}}^{p-1}}\to g_{0}}$
  weakly in $L^{1}(\Omega)$
  as $k\to\infty$
 , for some $g_{0}\in L^{1}(\Omega)$
 .

Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle w_n=\frac{g(x,u_n)}{\|u_n\|_{W^{1,p}}^{p-1}}$ and suppose that $\|u_n\|_{W^{1,p}}\geq1$ for all $n$.

We treat case $p>N$ first. In this case, $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\subset L^\infty(\Omega)$. So, the sequence $\{w_n\}$ is bounded in $L^1(\Omega)$. In order to extract a convergent subsequence for the weak-$*$ topology, it suffices show that this sequence is uniformly integrable, i.e., 
$$
  \lim_{M\to \infty} \sup_n \int_{|w_n|\geq M} |w_n|\,dx = 0.
$$
But
$$
  \sup_n\int_{|w_n|\geq M} |w_n|\,dx \leq \int_{a+d\,\gtrsim\, M} (a+d)\,dx \to 0 \quad\text{as $M\to\infty$,}
$$
which finishes the argument for $p>N$.

The case $p=N$ is a just a bit more complicated. Now, one has the estimate
$$
  |w_n| \lesssim a^r + |v_n|^{r'} + d. 
$$
The sequence $\{|v_n|^{r'}\}$ is uniformly integrable, since the embedding $W^{1,N}(\Omega)\subset L^{r'}(\Omega)$ is compact. In view of $a^r+d\in L^1(\Omega)$, one then proceeds as in the previous case.

Comment: What does the notation $\lesssim$ mean?

Comment: The inequality holds up to a multiplicative constant whose value is not important.